# Can discounts be combined?

Tags: cividiscount

I'm using the CiviDiscount extension and it works great - thank you.

Is it possible to combine an auto-discount (e.g. for qualifying logged-in members) and a manually entered discount (e.g. entered on an event registration page) combine? It's not working for me at the moment but am wondering if it's my set up or if this option is not available.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, the CiviDiscount module only allows one discount to be applied.  So you may want to consider utilizing one manually entered discount code that adds up to the total discount you're hoping to give (presumably only to certain members?).

Hope this helps,
Lesley